# How does scanf() work for strings in C99?

Tags: c, input, scanf

So I'm working on a documentary of learning the C Language and I want to make examples within pointers and input. Basically, I made a `Hello, (name).` program like this using C99:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *name;
    printf("What's your name? ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hello, %s.\n", name);
}
```

When I tried compiling it, the error it gave me was this:

```
C3.c:5:48: error: variable 'name' is uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
    printf("What is your name? "); scanf("%s", name);
                                               ^~~~
C3.c:4:17: note: initialize the variable 'name' to silence this warning
    char *name;
               ^
                = NULL
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'C3' failed
make: *** [C3] Error 1
```

So I modified line 2 into `char *result = "";`, which actually worked this time, but the output was this:

```
What's your name? Bro
Segmentation fault
```

This is a little confusing for me, since I'm not actually used to the `scanf()` function.

So my problem is, what would be a better way to get strings by input using `scanf()` in C99 without any weird output right after?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `int main(void)` was preferred in C99.  `int main()` is pretty old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` doesn't allocate any memory. You need to allocate the string's memory yourself. You should also specify the length `scanf` is allowed to read to avoid buffer overflows.

E.g.:

```
char name[21]; // 20 chars plus the null-terminator
printf("What's your name? ");
scanf("%20s", name);
```

Comment: `scanf("%19s", name);` would be better.

Comment: @WilliamPursell good point, thanks! Edited in an explanation about it.

Comment: Nice explanation about the `char *` problems. I will try it now.